# Add a bold female symbol to ggplot2 using annotate

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts, plotmath

I'm trying to use the female symbol, ♀ in my plot. It's pretty faint (well, it looks faint on my actual graph), so I was hoping to make it bold face.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(0, 1), y = c(0, 1))
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() +
   theme_bw() +
   annotate("text", x = 0.5, y = 0.7, label = "2016 ♀", 
   size = 7, hjust = 0, colour = "grey50")
```

[image: Plot with faint female symbol]

I've tried the following, but none seem to work:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() +
   annotate("text", x = 0.5, y = 0.7, label = "2016~bold(♀)", 
   size = 7, hjust = 0, parse = TRUE) 

# error message: Error in parse(text = as.character(lab)) : <text>:1:11: unexpected '<'
#1: 2016~bold(<
              ^

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() +
   annotate("text", x = 0.5, y = 0.7, label = "2016~bold(u2640)", 
   size = 7, hjust = 0, parse = TRUE) 

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() +
   annotate("text", x = 0.5, y = 0.7, label = "2016~bold(\u2640)", 
   size = 7, hjust = 0, parse = TRUE)
```

I also found [this post](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Male-and-female-signs-as-subscript-in-plot-td4670639.html), but I'm not sure if I can modify the following code to work within ggplot?

```
plot(df)
text( locator(1), "\\VE", vfont=c("sans serif","bold"), xpd=TRUE)  # Venus
```

Comment: You can add `fontface = 'bold'` to the `annotate` call, and `2016` will look bold, but `♀` looks the same on my screen. My guess is that the font just doesn't have a bold representation for that character?

Comment: Yeah, if you use "2016~(bold(infinity))" the infinity sign doesn't get bolded either...

Comment: You could try if other `family`s do have bold faces for those.

Answer (score 8):

@Axeman's comment helped me find an answer - I didn't realize you could load in other packages to get more fonts for ggplot2. Thanks! I used the following code:

```
install.packages("extrafont")
library(extrafont)
font_import() # Prepare for this to take several minutes
loadfonts(device = "win")

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() +
   theme_bw() +
   annotate("text", x = 0.5, y = 0.7, label = "2016 ♀", 
   size = 7, hjust = 0, colour = "grey50", family = "Calibri", fontface = "bold")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, How did you know family is an argument of annotate?
?annotate does not tell me that.

Comment: Hi @AlvaroMorales, in the help file you'll see in the list of arguments the `...,` argument. When you read the documentation it says, " `Other arguments passed on to layer(). These are often aesthetics, used to set an aesthetic to a fixed value, like colour = "red" or size = 3.` " The family argument is just another aesthetic, so it works here.